# im trying to do a Typing bot with delay

Tags: python, python-3.10

Is my code correct? I just want to check. and is there a way that I can make it better.

```
import time
import random

string = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"

def TypeDelay(string):
    for i in range(len(string)):
        delay = random.uniform(0,1.1)
        time.sleep(delay)
        print(string[i], end="")

TypeDelay(string)
```

Comment: What do you mean is the code "correct"?

Comment: like if I did it right? or is there something wrong with it? cuz i can't tell if the code just types at a constant speed of (0,1.1) it needs to change speed so that people won't know a bot is the one whos typing the string.

Comment: What's your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `flush` parameter to the `print()` function call to see the output immediately, otherwise the string will appear as a single blob of text.

In my code below I've added a generator to decouple the delay functionality from the print loop.

```
import random
import time

def characters_with_delay(str):
    for c in str:
        time.sleep(random.uniform(0, 1.1))
        yield c

s = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"

for c in characters_with_delay(s):
    print(c, end="", flush=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose following ameloration: use `for i in string` to get characters, rather than range-len to get indices, that is rather than

```
for i in range(len(string)):
    delay = random.uniform(0,1.1)
    time.sleep(delay)
    print(string[i], end="")
```

you might do

```
for i in string:
    delay = random.uniform(0,1.1)
    time.sleep(delay)
    print(i, end="")
```

Comment: May as well choose a better name than the integer-implying `i`.

Comment: @L3viathan yes feel free to do so, if you are concering with style of your code I suggest you read [PEP 8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/)